# Arrange messed up array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

In my app there's an array called `newArray` that contains a lot of numbers. The app sends the numbers to a server and puts them into a new array called `stalkers`. My problem is that some names are returned faster than others and the names in the `stalkers` array could be in any order. How can I make the order of the returned data be the same as the corresponding numbers in `newArray`?

So let's say `newArray = ["10002938948","46789890","2984829389"]`. My code sends it to a server and downloads the names. For "10002938948", the server returns "Tim". For "46789890" the server returns "Louis". For "2984829389", the server returns "Rob". Then it should be `stalkers = ["Tim","Louis","Rob"]`, but because they are not downloaded in order (one page loads faster than another), `stalkers = ["Louis","Rob","Tim"]`.

It should be something like I could give each number an id, so I can just sort the id's in the right order in the `stalkers` array.

Comment: There's really not enough information here to decipher your problem. Perhaps you could add: what you've tried so far, your dataset and your expected response.

Comment: "It should be something like I could give each number an id, so I can just sort the id's in the right order in the stalkers array" They _have_ ids - the values in `newArray`.

Comment: @matt yes I know they have id's but these id's are in the newArray, so when putting the result into the stalkers array, they lose their id and they are not in the same order and you can't sort them as far as I know..

Comment: _Don't_ put the result in the stalkers array. Key the results by the ids. Read my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary using the elements of `newArray` as the keys and the arriving name values as the values. When all the results have arrived, create the `stalkers` array by cycling through `newArray`, thus keeping the order.

```
let newArray=["10002938948","46789890","2984829389"]

// For 10002938948, the server returns Tim. 
// For 46789890 the server returns Louis.
// For 2984829389, the server returns Rob.
// Then it should be stalkers=["Tim","Louis","Rob"]

// As they arrive, store each result in a dictionary:

var d = [String:String]()

// note that the order of the next three statements doesn't matter!

// Tim arrives for 10002938948

d["10002938948"] = "Tim"

// Louis arrives for 46789890

d["46789890"] = "Louis"

// Rob arrives 2984829389

d["2984829389"] = "Rob"

// now assemble stalkers by cycling through newArray

let stalkers = newArray.map{d[$0]!} // ["Tim","Louis","Rob"]
```

Comment: How do I append the downloaded name to the dictionary?

Comment: Hey. My code does exactly what you said you needed to do. You said "I want it to be in the same order as the original and I have no idea how to do this." Well, now you know how to do it. I'm outta here.

Comment: There's no "though". Think about what I'm telling you.